# react-native inmutable object

Tags: react-native

Tengo que pasar el objeto options para crear una conexión socket, lo uso así:

```
    var options = {port: 4444, host: this.props.ip, reuseAddress: true};

    var client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options);
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
    You attempted to set the key 'host' with the value x.x.x.x on an object that is meant to be inmutable and has been frozen.
```

Como puedo clonar o copiar el valor this.props.ip (recibido como prop por el componente) para evitar este error?

**Edición:**
He intentado esto, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error:

```
    var self = this;
    var clone = Object.assign({}, self.props)

    var options = {port: 4444, host:clone.ip, reuseAddress: true};
```

Comment: Object.assign??

Comment: ya probé con Object.assign, y me da el mismo error

Comment: no conozco el problema de fondo probablemente la solucion sea otra, si quiers pasar un objeto usa [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

Answer (score 0):

Tengo que crear 2 sockets, si uso el mismo objeto options en los 2, obtengo ese error.

Lo solucioné creando una copia del objeto options para el segundo socket.